# how to stop blur event on calling reset of textfield

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

It appears that on calling reset event of textfield in ExtJS 4.2 the blur event is automatically called.

i have a scenario where in a form i have combo box and textfield, on select of combo box i am calling reset of textfield.

```
#cmbStatus : {
    select : function(combo, records, eOpts){
        combo.up('form').down('textfield[name=referencenumber]').reset();
    }
```

and on blur of textfield i am calling reset of combo box.

```
#txtRefNumber : {
    blur : function(cmp, The, eOpts){
        cmp.up('form').down('combobox').reset();
    }
}
```

here, because of the cascading effect on select of combo box, since reset is being called, the textfield blur event is automatically called and combo box reset event occurs

Is there any way i can stop the textfield blur event ?

I am aware about the suspendEvent method of textfield but no use as it will suspend the event till resumeEvent is called.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `blur` event is not fired as a direct result of calling `reset` but as a response to moving focus out of the text field.

You will probably need to reconsider and redesign the logic so that the event loop does not occur. Try to use a different event, for example `change`.

Also, calling suspendEvents might be necessary to avoid the event loop, depending on the logic you need.